# Converting an RGB image to grayscale in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to convert an RGB image to grayscale using **skimage** in Python. Here's what I do:

```
for im_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(pos_raw, "*")):
    im = imread(im_path)
    im = color.rgb2gray(im)
    image_name = os.path.split(im_path)[1].split(".")[0] + ".pgm"
    image_path = os.path.join(pos_img_path, image_name)
    imwrite(image_path, im)
```

for a bunch of image files.
My input image looks like this:

[image: Color image]

And the output image looks like this:

[image: Black image]

The expected output is this:

[image: Gray image]

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried breaking this into smaller parts? For example, do you know that the image is being read and saved correctly? Your code that converts to grayscale looks fine, I would check the file read/write sections. (I'm not actually familiar with `scikit-image`, just giving general advice)

Comment: Be sure to post your solution as an answer and accept it for others' future reference. Glad I helped.

Comment: Your code as above works fine for me, outputting a greyscale version of the image. However, I needed to use `imsave` instead of `imwrite`

Comment: @mfitzp that's great, apparently `imsave` automatically stretches the contrast. Got the following warning though `UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from float64 to uint8`. I guess that is fine by me though :)

Comment: Why you don't use the `imread_collection()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was of contrast.

I printed out the image and saw that the values were all close to 0. I introduced a small line to stretch the contrast between 0 and 255 in the loop that made it work.

```
im = rescale_intensity(im, out_range=(0, 255))
```

Where `rescale_intensity` was imported from `skimage.exposure`.